# Why can't I pass "directory" as component prop?

Tags: reactjs, react-proptypes, storybook

I'm trying to pass down props from container.js to flow.js. It's fine with cart, checkout and user props. But the directory prop isn't being passed down. How can I fix this? The only thing I can edit is my component and json. Not container or flow.

My component:

```
<Container directory={directoryVar} checkout={checkout} cart={cart} user={user} />
```

My const directoryVar:

```
const directoryVar = {
    countries: [
        {
            id: "AD",
            two_letter_abbreviation: "AD",
            three_letter_abbreviation: "AND",
            full_name_locale: "Andorra",
            full_name_english: "Andorra"
        },
        {
            id: "AE",
            two_letter_abbreviation: "AE",
            three_letter_abbreviation: "ARE",
            full_name_locale: "United Arab Emirates",
            full_name_english: "United Arab Emirates"
        }]};
```

container.js looks like this. It has values in it when I console.log it before the export. After the export, values are gone.

```
import { connect } from 'src/drivers';

import {
    beginCheckout,
    cancelCheckout,
    submitOrder,
    submitPaymentMethodAndShippingAddress,
    postAddressInformation,
    submitShippingAddress,
    submitBillingAddress,
    getStreetByPostCodeNLApi,
    setTotalsAreLoading
} from 'src/actions/checkout';

import Flow from './flow';

const mapStateToProps = ({ cart, checkout, directory, user }) => {
    console.log(user,directory);
    return {
        cart,
        checkout,
        directory,
        user
    };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = {
    beginCheckout,
    cancelCheckout,
    submitOrder,
    submitPaymentMethodAndShippingAddress,
    postAddressInformation,
    submitShippingAddress,
    submitBillingAddress,
    getStreetByPostCodeNLApi,
    setTotalsAreLoading
};

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(Flow);
```

Flow.js looks like this:

```
const isCheckoutReady = checkout => {
    const {
        billingAddress,
        paymentData,
        shippingAddress,
        shippingMethod
    } = checkout;

    const objectsHaveData = [
        billingAddress,
        paymentData,
        shippingAddress
    ].every(data => {
        return !!data && !isObjectEmpty(data);
    });

    const stringsHaveData = !!shippingMethod && shippingMethod.length > 0;

    return objectsHaveData && stringsHaveData;
};

/**
 * This Flow component's primary purpose is to take relevant state and actions
 * and pass them to the current checkout step.
 */
const Flow = props => {
    const {
        // state
        cart,
        checkout,
        user,
        directory,

        // actions
        cancelCheckout,
        submitShippingAddress,
        submitOrder,
        submitPaymentMethodAndShippingAddress,
        postAddressInformation,
        submitBillingAddress,
        setStepNumber,
        getStreetByPostCodeNLApi,
        setTotalsAreLoading
    } = props;
```

Output from console.log:

```
{} {user:...}
```

Comment: Could you please add the reducer snippet to understand more what exactly you're trying to do because your code in container.js seems to be buggy.

Comment: what is output from console inside `mapStateToProps`?

Comment: @Rikin User is correct, directory is empty.

Comment: Well then its not fault of Container or Flow components. It seems you are mixing up state props and `ownProps`

Comment: @Rikin Any workaround there? The propname needs to stay "directory"

Comment: Yes, writing up answer

Answer (score 0):

I think you are misunderstanding how to use redux.
The values that you pass down through props in the component are fine.

But the values you want to get in mapStateToProps, have to come from the redux store.

So for example, you have a reducer called user, that has an array called data.

Your mapStateToProps would be something like this:

```
mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    userData: state.user.data
  }
};
```

Comment: So why are the other values working fine, but directory is the only prop not getting passed down?

Comment: can you update your code with more info? I need to see specifically both files, Container and Flow.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are mixing up stateProps and ownProps. To understand that lets look at mapStateToProps function signature from the docs: https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapstate#defining-mapstatetoprops

> function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps?)

First argument passed to this function is your Redux state and second argument passed to this function are actual `props` that are passed to this component.

You are using your Container component as below:

```
<Container directory={directoryVar} checkout={checkout} cart={cart} user={user} />
```

So in that you are actually passing in props named `directory`, `checkout`, `cart` and `user`, they are your passed in `props` to the container.

Using your code snippet below, you can see you are deriving `directory`, `checkout`, `cart` and `user` from `state` and you are ignoring what is passed in as props to your `Container` component which happens to use same prop names as you have it in your state.

```
const mapStateToProps = ({ cart, checkout, directory, user }) => {
    console.log(user,directory);
    return {
        cart,
        checkout,
        directory,
        user
    };
};
```

In order to use passed in props, you would have to use it this way:

```
const mapStateToProps = (stateProps, ownProps) => {
    return {
       ...ownProps
    };
};
```

Now assume you also want to use additional prop `company` from your `state` of the application and pass it to your underlying component `Flow` then you would use it like below:

```
const mapStateToProps = ({ company } , ownProps) => {
    return {
       company,
       ...ownProps
    };
};
```

Comment: Is there any fix where I don't have to edit flow or container?

Comment: Since you mentioned you can only modify your component and dont want to edit Flow or Container, then that solution lies at redux reducer and how you are setting state property `directory`. Can you share those snippets on how `directory` is set

Comment: I want to use directory as a prop to pass my JSON directoryVar. So it's set in the component itself as far as I'm aware.

Comment: If you cant modify Container component then passing in any prop to that component is meaningless, the only other way would be to create `directory` in `state` and set its value somehow so that its consumed by function `mapStateToProps`